# OS X 10.11.3 Update, keyboard lagging

Tags: keyboard, macos

I don't know how to explain this, but since I've updated my OS X to 10.11.3, keyboard seems to lag. It's extremely subtle, but I am a programmer and an author, and I can feel the difference while coding or typing, and even it's something in the milliseconds-range, it's noticeable and disturbing. I've tried restarting etc, not using many programs at once, but no avail. It's noticeable everywhere, even as I'm typing this question here. I haven't installed anything extra.

I'm in a mid-2014 MacBook Pro with the built-in keyboard. The problem is keyboard language-independent. The problem occurs system-wise, from TextEdit to Safari to Xcode, even inside Windows apps using Parallels.

Is anyone having the same issue?

Comment: Your Description is too vague: What kind of keyboard (Apple USB, Apple Bluetooth etc.)? What kind of Mac (iMac, Mabook, Mabook Pro etc.)? In what environment is the situation occuring/what Software (XCode, Sublime Text, Word etc.)? Is the situation repeatable when it is happening, f.e. in other Software? Have you looked in the Console? If so post any possible relevant Entries.

Comment: @J.C. sorry, my bad. I've added some details.

Comment: no Probl. Try looking into the Console for strange entires. Apple has made major changes in the USB-Stack. Have you any other devices connected?

Comment: @J.C. I don't see anything strange in the console log, especially nothing related to USB or keyboard or input devices. I had my iPhone connected via USB, removed it, but no avail.

Comment: I have a similar issue, on both Macbook Pro (older bluetooth keyboard) and an iMac (newer bluetooth/lightning keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

I would try to disable some keyboard-related applications, if you have any. Such as:

- Karabiner
- Text Expander (I had one as extension for Google Chrome =)
- Punto Swither
- etc.

I have just got rid of the keyboard lags on my system by uninstalling all of these (it could be only one of them that caused the issue, but I've shot all three).

Comment: I've got Karabiner (Elements). But I think the problem went away by itself too